Mac M3 Pro `exec /usr/bin/java: exec format error` when trying to deploy docker image - already tried changing architectures; ContainerConfig?
I have seen existing posts that point to how to resolve this error which shows up when pushing from a Mac to a Linux server like on Amazon ECR: this post. However I am still getting the exec /usr/bin/java: exec format error when pushing.
My dockerfile looks like this:
# I have tried this as well.
#FROM --platform linux/amd64 amazoncorretto:11
FROM amazoncorretto:11

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app
# Copy the JAR file into the container at /app
COPY build/libs/messageReplay-0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
# Expose the port your app runs on
EXPOSE 8080
# Run the JAR file
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]

I have tried specifying the different architectures and approaches like the following:

docker build --platform linux/amd64 -t <repo>
docker push --platform linux/amd64 <repo>

My coworker is able to build with the identical Dockerfile above without getting this issue; they are on linux rather than mac.
I diff'd the docker inspect <image> results of my coworker's image and my own, and this is the diff (working one on left, mine with error on right): https://www.diffchecker.com/haWUcAff/
It is mostly the same, I verified that "Architecture": "amd64" is there for both, but notably the ContainerConfig field is missing. (Could this matter?) Suggestions appreciated.
--
Update: My local machine is mac, but I am pushing to Amazon ECR on Linux. I have tried both amd64 and arm64 and without specifying any --platform argument without success.
I find it strange that my teammate can push successfully. Please see the diff link above which shows the left image working (his, amd64) but not the right image (mine).

amd64 is intel x86_64 architecture.  Your macintosh is arm64.

...so assuming you're building and running the image locally, it should help to remove all of the --platform options everywhere, and Docker will use the local OS/processor.

Updated question - please take another look.

Have you purged docker of any older images from this build series that may be the wrong architecture?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65952339/8258079 also see this answer where the user has specified the platform within the Dockerfile FROM instruction.

Using
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 -t <tag> --output type=docker .

where --output ensures the image is available locally
and then docker tag and docker push as normal worked.
Also might need

The setting "Use containerd for pulling and storing images" to be enabled in Docker desktop settings
(Unclear if necessary) Docker - Cannot build multi-platform images with docker buildx for multi-platform support

